# how to replace Alert into navigation.navigate('Home")? like Open the new screen in catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

> How to open the new screen?

like: **navigation.navigate('Home")**

```
async function handleLoginWithPhonePressed() {
    try { 
        ------------------------
} 
catch (err) {
      //Alert.alert(`Failed to login with phone ${err.message}`)
        {() => navigation.navigate('Home")}
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please don't attach the screen shot, add the code in your question

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and imgur is blocked in some workplaces and countries. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: async function handleLoginWithPhonePressed() {
    try {
      const token = await AccountKit.loginWithPhone()

      if (!token) {
        Alert.alert('User cancelled the login with phone action!')
        return
      }

      setAuthToken(token)
      getCurrentUser()
    } catch (err) {
      Alert.alert(`Failed to login with phone ${err.message}`)
    }
  }

Comment: okay, I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this is right answer.**

> this.props.navigation.navigate('Home")

```js
async function handleLoginWithPhonePressed() {
    try { 
        ------------------------
} 
catch (err) {
      //Alert.alert(`Failed to login with phone ${err.message}`)
        //{() => navigation.navigate('Home")}
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question, cause you already answered yourself.

Replace Alert.alert with the code of router.

```
try{
 .....
}
catch{
//open the new screen or next page
//navigation.navigate("xyz")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function handleLoginWithPhonePressed() { 
  try { 
    const token = await AccountKit.loginWithPhone() 
    if (!token) { 
      Alert.alert('User cancelled the login with phone action!') 
        return 
     } 
     setAuthToken(token) 
     getCurrentUser() 
  } 
   catch (err) { 
    Alert.alert(Failed to login with phone ${err.message}) 
  } 
}
```